Merging two datasets of unequal length in R continuous error
I am trying to merge two datasets. One of them shows what activity each person did and their duration (separate row for each activity per person), and the other shows with whom the activity was done (new row for each person each activity was done with.) For anyone wondering it's the ATUS 2003-2022 data. Whenever I try to merge them by the person's ID I get the following error:

Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  :
Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

For reference, here is my code:
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

#convert to data table
atuswho_0322 <- data.table(atuswho_0322, key = "TUCASEID")
atussum_0322 <- data.table(atussum_0322, key = "TUCASEID")
atusact_0322 <- data.table(atusact_0322, key="TUCASEID")

#take out age and year columns from atussum
ageyr <- atussum_0322 %>%
  select(TUCASEID, TEAGE, TUYEAR)

#take out activity and duration from atusact
actdur <- atusact_0322 %>%
  select(TUCASEID, TUACTIVITY_N, TUACTDUR24)

#take out WHO
who <- atuswho_0322 %>%
  select(TUCASEID,TUWHO_CODE, TUACTIVITY_N) %>%
  filter(TUWHO_CODE %in% c("18", "19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","40","51", "53", "54", "61")) %>%
  mutate(TUWHO_CODE = recode(TUWHO_CODE,
                             "18" = "Alone",
                             "19" = "Alone",
                             "20" = "Partner",
                             "21" = "Partner",
                             "22" = "Children",
                             "24" = "Family",
                             "23" = "Family",
                             "25" = "Family",
                             "26" = "Family",
                             "53" = "Family",
                             "54" = "Friends",
                             "40" = "Children",
                             "61" = "Coworkers",
                             "51"= "Family"))

#combine who and the summary
final <- merge (who, actdur, by = "TUCASEID")

I am trying to make a time series graph with the year on the x axis, time spent on the Y axis, and a line for each category of people time was spent with (friends, coworkers, etc.)

Can you provide the data?

https://www.bls.gov/tus/data/datafiles-0322.htm I used the "Activity summary file" and the "Who file" ! @Edward

There are 30+ links on that page. Searching through them if it fits the description and download and unzip them is quite a task. To make this more approachable please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/9462095 . Also, as the error message stated, there might be duplicated IDs/keys, did you check that?

Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow so I'm not really familiar with how to post questions, but I'll take a look. Regarding duplicates, I'm pretty sure there are supposed to be there since each key represents an individual, so for an individual doing 5 things in one day the same key will come up 5 times, hence why I'm not sure how to deal with this.

No worries. You have to decide what to do in the case of duplicates. Maybe there are other variables you can merge by, a kind of sub-group that makes the IDs unique, e.g. merge (who, actdur, by = c("TUCASEID", "TUWHO_CODE")).

See this minimal example df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6), dat=LETTERS[1:8]); df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(2,4,4,5,5), dat=LETTERS[1:5]); merge(df1, df2, "ID"). It generates 6 entries with ID == 4. So you have to decide  how to deal with those combined results and whether you need all of them. Maybe work with a subset of your original data and see what's desired.

I think TUACTIVITY_N is an identifier for the activity number by person, so there are 4,508,883 activities across all people? Joining by this variable too gives the expected number of rows:
merge(who, actdur, by = c("TUCASEID", "TUACTIVITY_N"))
#>                TUCASEID TUACTIVITY_N TUWHO_CODE TUACTDUR24
#>       1: 20030100013280            1      Alone         60
#>       2: 20030100013280            4      Alone        150
#>       3: 20030100013280            5    Partner          5
#>       4: 20030100013280            6      Alone        175
#>       5: 20030100013280            9      Alone        140
#>      ---                                                  
#> 4508879: 20221212222501           21      Alone         45
#> 4508880: 20221212222501           22      Alone         15
#> 4508881: 20221212222501           23      Alone         15
#> 4508882: 20221212222501           24      Alone        240
#> 4508883: 20221212222501           25      Alone         30

